# KendoUI MVC Grid Update Operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, telerik-mvc

I am using the KendoUI controls for the first time and I'd like to know how to accomplish the next:

This is my view model:

```
public class OrderViewModel
{        
    public string ClientId { get; set; }

    public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    public Category MainCategory { get; set; }

    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }

    public OrderViewModel()
    {
        Items = new List<Item>(); Categories = new List<Category>();
    }
}
```

This is the Item Class:

```
public class Item
{   
    [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int ItemId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Name")]
    public string ItemName { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Quantity")]
    [DataType("Integer")]
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Price")]
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Category class:

```
public class Category
{
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I want to show that information using a TextBox, a DropDownList and a Grid:

```
@(Html.Kendo().TextBox()
            .Name("client")
            .Value(@Model.ClientId)
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
        )

@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
            .Name("categories")
            .DataTextField("Name")
            .DataValueField("CategoryId")
            .BindTo(@Model.Categories)
            .Value(@Model.MainCategory.CategoryId.ToString())
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
        )
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Items)
            .Name("items")
            .Columns(columns => 
            {
                columns.Bound(a => a.ItemId);
                columns.Bound(a => a.ItemName);
                columns.Bound(a => a.Price);
                columns.Bound(a => a.Quantity);
            })
            .ToolBar(toolBar =>
            {
                toolBar.Save().SaveText("Send").CancelText("Cancel");
            })
            .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
            .Scrollable()
            .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                .ButtonCount(5)
            )
            .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
            .DataSource(datasource => datasource
                .Ajax()
                .Batch(true)
                .PageSize(30)
                .ServerOperation(false)
                .Model(model =>
                {
                    model.Id(a => a.ItemId);
                    model.Field(a => a.Name).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(a => a.Price).Editable(false);
                    model.Field(a => a.Quantity);
                })
                .Update(update => update.Action("SendOrder","Orders"))
            )
        )
```

The information is shown correctly, the user should enter a ClientId, select a category and enter the quantity for each item in the grid, I want to save the information the user entered in the controls when the user click the save button in the Grid Toolbar.

How can I pass the updated model to the "SendOrder" action?

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult SendOrder(....)
    {
        //Code to save the information

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: [Check this demo on telerik site, its exactly what you need](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing)

Comment: Thanks, let me check that demo.

Answer (score 0):

After checking this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/grid/editing) and this [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/ajax-binding#pass-additional-data-to-the-action-method)

I could pass the data from the model to the action, this is my final code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Items)
        .Name("items")
        .Columns(columns => 
        {
            columns.Bound(a => a.ItemId);
            columns.Bound(a => a.ItemName);
            columns.Bound(a => a.Price);
            columns.Bound(a => a.Quantity);
        })
        .ToolBar(toolBar =>
        {
            toolBar.Save().SaveText("Send").CancelText("Cancel");
        })
        .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
        .Scrollable()
        .Pageable(pageable => pageable
            .ButtonCount(5)
        )
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
        .DataSource(datasource => datasource
            .Ajax()
            .Batch(true)
            .PageSize(30)
            .ServerOperation(false)
            .Model(model =>
            {
                model.Id(a => a.ItemId);
                model.Field(a => a.Name).Editable(false);
                model.Field(a => a.Price).Editable(false);
                model.Field(a => a.Quantity);
            })
            .Update(update => update.Action("SendOrder","Orders").Data("getAdditionalData"))
        )
    )

function getAdditionalData() {

    var cat = $("#categories").val();
    var cli = $("#client").val();

    return {
        clientId: cli,
        categoryId: cat
    }
}
```

To pass additional parameters (client id and category) to the action I use the Data method and I provide the name of a JavaScript function which will return a JavaScript object with the additional data.

The action:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult SendOrder([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, [Bind(Prefix = "models")]List<Item> items, string clientId, string categoryId)
        {
           //code to save information

            return View();
        }
```

I don't know if there is a better way to accomplish this, but this is working for me.